# How can I use android emulator , it's showing emulator already running?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, flutter, visual-studio-code

I was running android studio emulator with my visual studio code for flutter app development. I have closed the previous emulator and tried to start it again but I got the following error.

[image]

I have even tried to delete all its services and restarted the android studio also but still facing the same problem. Is there any service or way to resolve this without restarting the system as it is happening with me several times?

Comment: Have you done what it said, and deleted the `*.lock` file?

Comment: It was not able to delete also that lock file

Comment: Lock file can't be deleted unless qemu-system-x86_64.exe is running and from task manager also not able to stop this process.